# How to make a Regular expression to remove all timestamp data from Chess Pgn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-chess

I have a string with the Pgn from a chess.com match. I need to remove all of the time data from the Pgn. Using Regular Expressions how would I accomplish this?

'1. e4 {[%clk 0:29:59.9]} 1... e5 {[%clk 0:29:59.1]} 2. Nf3 {[%clk 0:29:58]} 2... Nf6 {[%clk 0:29:57.2]} 3. Nc3 {[%clk 0:29:51.9]} 3... Bb4 {[%clk 0:29:51.9]} 4. a3 {[%clk 0:29:49.4]} 4... Ba5 {[%clk 0:29:46.3]} 5. Bc4 {[%clk 0:29:44.7]} 5... O-O {[%clk 0:29:37.5]} 6. Ng5 {[%clk 0:29:37.9]} 6... d6 {[%clk 0:29:10]} 7. O-O {[%clk 0:29:35.7]} 7... Be6 {[%clk 0:28:41.8]} 8. Nxe6 {[%clk 0:29:19]} 8... fxe6 {[%clk 0:28:33.2]} 9. b4 {[%clk 0:29:13.9]} 9... Bb6 {[%clk 0:28:21.6]} 10. a4 {[%clk 0:29:08.4]} 10... d5 {[%clk 0:27:53.9]}

I would like to remove all of the timestamps with {[%clk ]} and some timestamp.

The expected string after should be:

'1. e4 1... e5 2. Nf3 2... Nf6' and so on

Comment: Can you pare down your sample to the minimum and then also show the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{\[%clk \d+:\d+:\d+(\.\d+)?\]}
```

### [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/y69c3w/1)